# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'- OPENRPWSET

Tags: sql, sql-server, openrowset

I am trying to load data into SQL server table. here is my code;

```
from OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB', 'Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;',
        'EXEC [dbo].[sp_model1]   @model   = ''predict1''',
         'EXEC [dbo].[sp_model2]   @model1    =  ''predict2''',
               @q =''SELECT *   FROM [tcs].[dbo].[fact_FY2019_FY2021]
                                where
                                [date] >= ''''2021-02-03 00:00:00''''
                              and  id = 11 order by key;'''
)as a
GO
```

Every time i run my insert statement along with above code, i get the following error

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
```

Not sure why am i getting this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check your quotes 'EXEC ............... ''predict1''',
        'EXEC   ..........  ''predict2''',       https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8c50da3628214405bd0419078fcdcac2

Comment: i did. tried all possible ways to figure that out. dont know still getting that error

Comment: checked and updated my ques with missing quotes. still the same

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here ? You are executing 2 stored procedure here. `OPENROWSET` will not be able to return multiple result set

Comment: Please do check the documentation for the correct syntax and usage of the function

Comment: I have created a sp which has two model outputs. now I am trying to insert that into a table. Hence i was trying to execute two sp's. how to execute a single sp with two models?

Comment: create another `stored procedure` that execute these two sp

Comment: `order by key` isn't going to work, as a side note; `KEY` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: maybe putting the 'SELECT *   FROM [tcs].[dbo].[fact_FY2019_FY2021] where [date] >= ''2021-02-03 00:00:00'' and  id = 11 order by key;'''  statement om one row